# Uniqueness of domain with given interior Newtonian potential

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, potential-theory, inverse-problems

The Newtonian potential of a domain $\Omega$ is defined by 
$\Gamma*\chi_{\Omega}$ ($\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of Laplacian operator $\Delta$), i.e. the convolution of the indicator function of $\Omega$ and the fundamental solution of $\Delta$.

Suppose I have two domains $\Omega_1$, $\Omega_2$ and $\operatorname{int}(\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2)\neq \phi$. Then denote their Newtonian potential function by $U_1$ and $U_2$. If I know $U_1=U_2$ in $\operatorname{int}(\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2)$, can we say $\Omega_1=\Omega_2$?

Or under what kind of condition we can say $\Omega_1=\Omega_2$?

Comment: If we allow $\Omega_2$ disconnected, then the answer is **no**: a counterexample is $\Omega_1 = B(0, 2)$ and $\Omega_2 = B(0, 1) \cup (B(0, 2+r) \setminus \overline B(0, 2))$ for an appropriate $r$.

Comment: Use $\operatorname{int}(U)$ `\operatorname{int}(U)`, not int$(U)$ `int$(U)$`.  I have edited accordingly.